# sql query different column based on input

Tags: sql

I am using MS-SQL 2008.  I have a table with different columns based on locations in it that will have a 'Y' or Null value.  The table also has other data other than location from survey results.  I have set up a temptable @TempLocation to hold the location based on the one or all.  I need to select rows from the table based on 'Y' from one or more location rows within a date range.

```
TableID Northwest Northeast Southwest Southeast Batchno first_choice date_completed
1       Y                   Y         Y         1       A            2012-11-10
2                 Y                   Y         1       SA           2012-19-10       
3       Y         Y                             1       N            2012-07-10
4       Y         Y                   Y         2       A            2012-10-10
5                           Y                   2       A            2012-16-10
6       Y                             Y         2       D            2012-21-10
7                 Y                             NULL    A            2012-19-10
8       Y         Y         Y         Y         3       SA           2012-11-10
9       Y                                       3       A            2012-10-10
10                          Y         Y         3       A            2012-07-10
```

I have created a Dynamic SQL statement to pull one location successfully but is it possible to pull all of them?

```
select  ''' + (SELECT * FROM @TempLocation) + ''',
count(batchno),
count(case when first_choice is not null then batchno end),
count(case when t.First_choice =''SD'' then 1 end) ,
count(case when t.First_choice=''D'' then 1 end) ,
count(case when t.First_choice=''N'' then 1 end) ,
count(case when t.First_choice=''A'' then 1 end) ,
count(case when t.First_choice=''SA'' then 1 end) 
from    customer_satisfaction_survey t
where   t.date_completed>= ''' + CAST(@beg_date AS VARCHAR) + '''
and     t.date_completed < ''' + CAST(dateadd(day,1,@end_date) AS Varchar) + '''
and     t.' + (SELECT * FROM @TempLocation) + ' = ''Y'''
```

An All result would look like this.

```
Number  Location   Total  Total2  SA  A  N  D  SD
1       Northwest  6      6       1   3  1  1  0
2       Northeast  5      4       2   2  1  0  0
3       Southwest  4      4       1   3  0  0  0
4       Southeast  6      6       2   3  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to think that you are approaching this in the wrong way, because your data is not normalized.  The first thing you should do is to normalize the data using `UNPIVOT`.  I'm assuming that you are using SQL Server, since your syntax suggests that.  It is a good idea to tag all questions with the database, though.

You can unpivot your data with a statement such as:

```
select BatchNo, FirstChoice, DateCompleted, Location
from d
unpivot (val for location in (Northwest, Northeast, Southwest, Southeast)) as unpvt
```

Next, set up your temporary table to have a separate row for each location.  Then, you can do the join with no dynamic SQL.  Something like:

```
with dnorm as (
    THE NORMALIZATION QUERY HERE
)
select dnorm.location, count(*) as total,
       sum(case when dnorm.first_choice is not null then 1 else 0 end) as total2,
       sum(case when dnorm.first_choice = 'SA' then 1 else 0 end) as SA,
       . . .
from dnorm join
     @TempLocation tl
     on dnorm.location = tl.location
where ALL YOUR WHERE CONDITIONS HERE
```

The final query looks something like:

```
with dnorm as (
    select BatchNo, FirstChoice, DateCompleted, Location
    from d
    unpivot (val for location in (Northwest, Northeast, Southwest, Southeast)) as unpvt
)
select dnorm.location, count(*) as total,
       sum(case when dnorm.first_choice is not null then 1 else 0 end) as total2,
       sum(case when dnorm.first_choice = 'SA' then 1 else 0 end) as SA,
       . . .
from dnorm join
     @TempLocation tl
     on dnorm.location = tl.location
where ALL YOUR WHERE CONDITIONS HERE
```

The dynamic SQL approach is quite clever, but I don't think it is the simplest way to approach this.

Comment: I have not had a lot of practice with Common Table Expressions. THE NORMALIZATION QUERY HERE appears in the second query to me to represent the survey table.  When I use SELECT statement the dnorm.location becomes invalid as there is no location column in the customer_satisfaction_survey table.

Comment: @MichaelRowley . . . Does the unpivot query work by itself?  It defines the location column, kind of by "cycling" through each of the "Y" or NULL columns.

Comment: Yeah the Unpivot query worked great!  Thank you for the help.